# Doxygen: warning: \dir command matches multiple directories

Tags: c, doxygen

I want to add some documentation to a folder, so in one of my files I add

```
/**
 * \dir sources
 * \details Adding details ...
 */
```

I also have a folder called `testsources` and Doxygen seems to be getting confused:

```
    warning: \dir command matches multiple directories.
    Applying the command for directory D:/Documents/ESW/sources/
    Ignoring the command for directory D:/Documents/ESW/testsources/
```

I've tried a few things, added trailing `\` or `/`, quotes, but the confusion remains...

Comment: From the documentation: "Indicates that a comment block contains documentation for a directory. The "path fragment" argument should
include the directory name and enough of the path to be unique with respect to the other directories in the project." So in your case I think "/sources" would do.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a valid answer I copied the [comment from albert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373967/doxygen-warning-dir-command-matches-multiple-directories#comment56882489_30373967):

> From the documentation: "Indicates that a comment block contains documentation for a directory. The "path fragment" argument should include the directory name and enough of the path to be unique with respect to the other directories in the project." So in your case I think "/sources" would do.

Comment: Ha, at least you call out what you've done.  But still a bit shallow to grab a comment from 8 years ago about a suspected solution, and submit it as your answer.

Comment: @Michael Quote: "Ha, at least you call out what you've done." Yes, of course! Because it's not my answer. And I also wrote why. It is not my intention to collect votes. I hate to find the answer in comments. It's time consuming.